# "Cannot find overload ..." on 'New' method - Powershell reflection.assembly instantiating a VB.NET class

Tags: vb.net, powershell, constructor

I have a .NET EXE file that has two 'New' methods; One New method accepts four parameters, the other accepts no parameters.

The end goal is to be able to reference this EXE via either Powershell or a different .NET app, to pass it these 4 parameters and thus not need to interact with the window, while still being able to manually launch the application and interact with it.

My methods are as follows (Currently not doing anything w/ parameters, haven't gotten that far):

```
Public Sub New(OrganizationName As String, ExpirationDate As String, ProductID As String, SerialNumber As String)

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
```

**I am referencing the compiled EXE from a Powershell script to test this at the moment**, and seem to be having trouble doing so.

When I attempt to pass these parameters to the class, I get an error message that no overload can be found with this number of parameters.

My powershell script:

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadFile("app.exe")
$App = New-Object App.AppMain("Test", "01/01/2017", "1001", "1234")
```

In the example above, 'App.exe' is the full filepath of my compiled EXE, and 'App' is subbed in for the project name. 'AppMain' is the main class of the application, it's a class name inside an 'AppMain.vb' file.

I can perform this without issue if I don't send parameters, and can later execute 'ShowDialog()' on the $App object to bring up the form, but don't get past the New-Object line if I try to send parameters.

> To be clear my question is **how should I be sending parameters to the constructor (New) method in my VB.NET application when I try to invoke the class in Powershell?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you are using to instantiate the object may be incorrect. I'm aware of two ways that this can be done.

Because you're using the `New-Object` cmdlet, we'll analyze the help for that first:

`New-Object [-TypeName] <String> [[-ArgumentList] <Object[]>]`

The `TypeName` parameter is required, and is of type `System.String`. This gets passed -- somehow -- to a reflection library (obviously - it's dynamic). The second is the `ArgumentList` parameter. The `[[] ]` notation means it's optional. The parameter, when used, accepts an array of values. Arrays in PowerShell can be typed a number of ways, but the simplest method is to provide a comma-delimited list, like so:

```
# ArgumentNullException has a pretty straight forward parameter list.
# It takes a param name, then an exception message. This is for demo only.
$paramName = "type"
$message  = "The type name provided could not be resolved."
New-Object -TypeName System.ArgumentNullException -ArgumentList $paramName, $message
```

Thus, your code should probably be written as:

```
$App = New-Object App.AppMain "Test", "01/01/2017", "1001", "1234"
```

The other way is to invoke the constructor directly. This is just using the calling convention for .NET methods in PowerShell. You can always invoke (public) constructors *as-if* they were static methods on a type, using the `new` method. PowerShell exposes this for constructors. You could do it (approximately) like so:

```
$App = [App.AppMain]::new("Test", "01/01/2017", "1001", "1234")
```

---

As long as your VB.NET class is a public class, is properly loaded (which is testable), and the constructor routine is public (which it is in your example), either example I've provided should work.

Comment: In the end I realized I was calling an outdated EXE file in the same folder from before I had renamed the compiled EXE that was being generated.... But your answer was great. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent! That is indeed the challenge with trying to load custom code into PowerShell, and where an IDE can really help out.